# fadeIn, fadeOut animation doesn't work well

Tags: jquery

I have this three sections ,I want a when click on `#startBtn` the current `section#step1`  hides gradually to the left and `section#step2` displays gradually,and like that happens when click on `#nextBtn` where `section#step2` hides
and display `section#step3`.

I get a problem that `section#step1` doesn't hide and `section#step3` doesn't display when click on `#nextBtn`.

Another question, how can I make the `#nextBtn` disable until the user change the value of `input[text]`, If there a property for disable? I try to manipulation with the `nextBtn` opacity,but I don't know how to unbind it from the hover and click events.
Can anyone help me.
Thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/R_soft/R2RYs/1

Comment: Yes, buttons have a disabled attribute. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#Attributes

Comment: Hi isherwood,so I should replace the <a> tag with button tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to completely hide the element and its contents by setting its width to 0 you should probably set CSS property `overflow:hidden;`.

The `section#step3` doesn't show because the `#nextBtn` has `href=""` so it's reference to the current document and just refreshes the page on click. You need to prevent the default `<a>` click handler by setting `e.preventDefault();`

```
$('#nextBtn').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); .....
```

As for the `#nextBtn` disabling, just add a class and you use the CSS3 selector `:not()` and set it on your hover state `#uiHome p a.button:not(.disabled):hover`. Not all browser supports this, but you can also apply a new hover state styles for the `.disabled` so it will override the previously set hover state.

```
#uiHome p a.button.disabled {
 opacity: .6;
 filter: alpha(opacity=60);
}

#uiHome p a.button.disabled:hover {
 color:#267BB6;
 background:white ;
 background-image:none ;
}
```

Instead of `blur()` I think it's better to add the disabling handler on input change event:

```
$('#uname').on('input propertychange', function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "") {
        $('#nextBtn').addClass("disabled");
    }else {
        $('#nextBtn').removeClass("disabled");
    }
});
```

See this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/R2RYs/2/

Comment: thanks Mark,I get a good information.so,If i also wana  unbind the click event for #nextBtn I try with this http://jsfiddle.net/R_soft/R2RYs/4/ but it doesn't work

Comment: Well your bind/unbind handler is on `$('#uname').on('input propertychange', function() {` so it's not yet fired unless the user  typed in inside the `<input>` field. And you've also attached a `click()` event before that `$('#nextBtn').click(next);`. To fix this you can either remove that `click()` event or trigger the input change event - `.trigger('input');`. See [http://jsfiddle.net/R2RYs/5/](http://jsfiddle.net/R2RYs/5/)